# Detect when iframe blocked and send to placeholder instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Sites like youtube block the displaying of their site from iframes.

I'd like to detect when an iframe fails to load due to blocking from the destination site, and instead load a placeholder address in the iframe.

Right now you get an empty iframe or a server error page, which is not user friendly.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I was thinking of using a web-bug to see if the frame loaded or not...  Or maybe a callback from the iframe to the main page.

Comment: I believe the only reliable way to do this, is to fetch the url serverside, and check for `x-frame-options` headers. For obvious reasons javascript is very limited when it comes to framebusting.

Comment: thanks guys.....looks like I'm in for a fun ajax round trip of doom then......yay